# AlignmentProperties do not work under TabViewItem.Content

Tags: uwp-xaml

If I use a PivotItem instead of WinUI's TabView control, the RichEditBox expands to full page. However, when using it with TabView, the RichEditBox only takes one a line worth of space like so: https://prnt.sc/ravdw6

Setting the height property of the RichEditBox to a constant like 800 works but don't like using constants in UI. Here's the code in question:

```
<muxc:TabView x:Name="Tabs"
              AddTabButtonClick="Tabs_AddTabButtonClick"
              Grid.Column="1"
              Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <muxc:TabView.TabItems>
                <muxc:TabViewItem Header="Entry 1">
                    <muxc:TabViewItem.IconSource>
                        <muxc:SymbolIconSource Symbol="NewFolder" />
                    </muxc:TabViewItem.IconSource>
                    <muxc:TabViewItem.Content>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <RichEditBox x:Name="MainRichEdit"
                                         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                         VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </muxc:TabViewItem.Content>
                </muxc:TabViewItem>
            </muxc:TabView.TabItems>
        </muxc:TabView>
```

Comment: Hi @dydx, Does the following solution works in your side?

Comment: Let me give it a try . Also, I already had the ``TabView`` inside a root grid which you can see because I've set the Grid's column and rowspan properties already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> AlignmentProperties do not work under TabViewItem.Content

I found the problem, you need use `Grid` as root container, and set `TabView`   `VerticalAlignment` property as **Stretch** like the following.

```
<Grid x:Name="RootGrid">
    <muxc:TabView x:Name="MyTabView" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        AddTabButtonClick="Tabs_AddTabButtonClick"
        >
        <muxc:TabView.TabItems>
            <muxc:TabViewItem Header="Entry 1">
                <muxc:TabViewItem.IconSource>
                    <muxc:SymbolIconSource Symbol="NewFolder" />
                </muxc:TabViewItem.IconSource>
                <muxc:TabViewItem.Content>
                    <Grid>
                        <RichEditBox 
                            x:Name="MainRichEdit"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                            />
                    </Grid>

                </muxc:TabViewItem.Content>
            </muxc:TabViewItem>
        </muxc:TabView.TabItems>
    </muxc:TabView>
</Grid>
```